# Image link inside .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

Fairly new to this.

I have a dynamic area depending on what is in the URL. That part works fine but how do I get the image to be a clickable image link? The image displays fine in my code below. Can someone show me how to add the URL i want it to go to when clicked? Thanks

```js
var para = document.createElement("p");

$(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("thank") > -1) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="<img src=\"https://exampleimage.com/button.PNG\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\">";
}
```

Comment: Have you tried surrounding the `<img>` tag with a `<a>` tag containing the desired url? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do i make an image clickable in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42051528/how-do-i-make-an-image-clickable-in-html)

Comment: unfortunately this doesnt work because it has to work with javascript.

Answer (score 3):

```
var para = document.createElement("p");

$(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("thank") > -1) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="<a href='https://www.google.com'><img src=\"https://exampleimage.com/button.PNG\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\"></a>";
  }
});
```

Wrap it inside  tag

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. Now it won't show the image at all.

Comment: You should use single quotes in that part e.g. `"<a href='https://www.google.com'><im...` because otherwise it is going to interpret the URL as actual code and not as a string. It should work like this btw