# How to use pictures as links in this gallery?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, gallery

I'm trying to use this gallery:
https://codepen.io/knyttneve/pen/YgZbLO

If I use a href, the picture doesn't show anymore

```
 <div class="box">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1000x800">
    <span>CSS</span>
```

But I don't know to use the pictures as links, when hovered over.

Comment: <div class="box"><a href=""><img src=""></a></div>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42051528/how-do-i-make-an-image-clickable-in-html

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap them in  tag:

```
<div class="box">
    <a href="..."><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1000x800"></a>
    <span>CSS</span>
</div>
```

CSS Code something like this:

```
.box img {
  object-fit: cover; 
  transition: .5s;
}

.box > a {
  width: 200%;
  height: calc(100% - 10vh);
}
```

Comment: But if I do that, the picture no longer changes size, and the imige title span disappears too

Comment: no, why should it? you can style it just normally and the span stays aswell. If it disappears or youc ant change the size of an image anymore, then this is caused by somethign else you did.